# GRASS r.in.lidar projection error

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis, lidar, las

I'm trying to import a laz file in GRASS using the command:

`r.in.lidar input=3dm_32_322_5593_1_nw.laz output=count_1 method=n resolution=1 -o -e -n`

and get:

> ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 7837 not found in EPSG support files. Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?

The projection is 25832 and I can open the file in QGis with LAStools without any problem.

Here a metadata snippet from the lasinfo tool:

---

GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 5

key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeProjected

key 3072 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 25832 - ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey: ETRS89 / UTM 32N

key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter

key 4099 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - VerticalUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter

key 4096 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 7837 - VerticalCSTypeGeoKey: Deutsches Haupthoehennetz 2016

---

To me it seems that GRASS confuses the projected and vertical CRS. Has anyone an idea how to fix the error or a workaround? Is there a way to skip the projection check (-o flag doesn't seem to work in this case) or to define the EPSG code any other way?

The dataset can be found here:
https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/hm/3dm_l_las/3dm_l_las/

Comment: I was able to import one of the data files by first converting the laz to txt using `las2txt`, then using `r.in.xyz`. I prepared a Location based on ETRS UTM32 in advance. The `r.in.xyz` module allows different methods, like `r.in.lidar` including "n" to get a count of Lidar points for each pixel. HTH

Comment: Note that `r.in.lidar` is pretty outdated since it based on the old `liblas`. Recommendation: use PDAL, there is https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.in.pdal.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I decided to use the lidaR package in R.